# I want to to append to each line the same string in lower case

Tags: bash, shell, append, pipe

I got a text file txt.txt with the following:

```
ABc
aBc
aBCD
BLAblaBLA
```

and other mixed case strings.

I want to to append to each line the same string in lower case (basically to add a second column), so it'll look like this:

```
ABc abc
aBc abc
aBCD abcd
BLAblaBLA blablabla
```

I got the lowercasing part done with this command:

```
cat txt.txt | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
```

but I'm racking my brains trying to add each line as an append to the txt.txt file.

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed` you can do the following:

```
sed -i 's/.*/& \L&/' txt.txt
#   ^     ^  ^  ^^
#   |     |  |  |Whole match
#   |     |  |  Lowercase
#   |     |  Whole match
#   |     Match whole line
#   In place edit, use -i.bak to take a backup.
```

The literal space between `&` and `\L` can be anything you want.

Comment: Case conversion works in some `sed` dialects, but not in others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `paste` to combine columns from different sources:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < txt.txt | paste txt.txt -
```

If you want to separate the columns by a space, add `-d' '` to `paste`.

Answer (score 2):

The missing command to  join files horizontally is [paste](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste):

```
 tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <txt.txt |paste txt.txt -
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple Awk script seems like both the most efficient and the most readable portable solution.

```
awk '{ print $0, tolower($0) }' txt.txt
```